# ¿Cómo copiar el ancho de una(s) columna(s) de un datatable a otro?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, datatables

Yo defino las columna de un datatable de la siguiente manera:

```
var table = $('#table_listado').DataTable({
        destroy: true,
        "scrollY": "250px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "searching": false,
        "paging": false,
        "ordering": false,
        "info": false,
        "columns": [
        { "width": "7%" },
        { "width": "6%" },
        { "width": "7%" },
        { "width": "4%" },
        { "width": "12%"},
        { "width": "8%" },
        { "width": "8%" },
        { "width": "8%" }
        ],
        fixedHeader: {
            header: true,
            footer: true
        }
    });
```

Donde me quedaría una tabla con estos anchos de columnas así, por decir un ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El caso, está en que quiero crear otra tabla, en donde ciertas columnas tengan el misma tamaño que la primera tabla definida, teniendo un resultado final asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si se fijan bien, la columna 5,6,7,8 de la primera tabla, estan alineados bien con la la columna 2,3,4 y 5 de la segunda tabla, siendo esto lo que deseo.

Pero si defino los anchos de las columnas con jquery de la misma forma como lo hice arriba, y copiando el mismo porcentaje de ancho, no queda con los anchos iguales a la primera tabla, porque creo que el ancho, aparte de definirse, va a depender del contenido de la tabla, donde se va ajustando automáticamente.
No se si me explicado bien, pero mi objetivo es que la segunda tabla o datatable que creo, tenga el misma ancho de la(s) columna(s) de la primera tabla. Espero sus respuestas. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var width_td0 = $('#table1 td').eq(0).width();
  var width_th0 = $('#table1 th').eq(0).width();
  var width_td1 = $('#table1 td').eq(1).width();
  var width_th1 = $('#table1 th').eq(1).width();
  var width_td2 = $('#table1 td').eq(2).width();
  var width_th2 = $('#table1 th').eq(2).width();
  
  
       $('#table2 th').eq(0).width(width_th0);
       $('#table2 td').eq(0).width(width_td0);
       $('#table2 th').eq(1).width(width_th1);
       $('#table2 td').eq(1).width(width_td1);
       $('#table2 th').eq(2).width(width_th2);
       $('#table2 td').eq(2).width(width_td2);
  
       console.log("Medida tabla 1 td["+$('#table1 td').eq(0).width()+"px]")
       console.log("Medida tabla 2 td["+$('#table2 td').eq(0).width()+"px]")
  });
```

```css
table { /*Esto para que acepte el width*/
        table-layout: fixed; 
  /*Muy Importante para que cuadre la medida*/
  border-spacing: 0; 
        width: 100%;
      }
table td{ 
          /*Esto por el desbordamiento del texto*/
          word-break: break-all; 
    text-align: center;
       padding: 5px;
        }
table th {
     padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <th style="width:7%; background-color:blue;">Column t1_1</th>
    <th style="width:6%; background-color:red;">Column t1_2</th> 
    <th style="width:7%; background-color:Yellow;">Column t1_3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abcdefghijkabcdefghijkabcdefghijk</td>
    <td>abcdefghijkabcdefghijkabcdefghijk</td>
    <td>abcdefghijkabcdefghijkabcdefghijk</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>abcdefghijk</td>
    <td>abcdefghijk</td>
    <td>abcdefghijk</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr/>
<table id="table2">
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color:purple;">Column t2_1</th>
    <th style="background-color:white;">Column t2_2</th> 
    <th style="background-color:black;">Column t2_3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abcdefghijkabcdefghijk</td>
    <td>abcdefghijkabcdefghijkabcdefghijk</td>
    <td>abcdefghijkabcdefghijkabcdefghijk</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>abcdefghijkabcdefghijkabcdefghijk</td>
    <td>abcdefghijk</td>
    <td>abcdefghijk</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: entonces como debería usarlo si tengo los anchos definidos de la primera tabla así:

var table = $('#table_listado').DataTable({
        "columns": [
        { "width": "7%" },
        { "width": "6%" },
        { "width": "7%" },
        { "width": "4%" },
        { "width": "12%"},
        { "width": "8%" },
        { "width": "8%" },
        { "width": "8%" }
        ],
        fixedHeader: {
            header: true,
            footer: true
        }
    });

Comment: @Danilo Modifique mi respuesta con un ejemplo mas concreto